# Using mapView:didAddAnnotationViews: from MKMapViewDelege and MGLMapViewDelegate errors

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mapbox, mglmapview

In my `UIViewController` I use both `MKMapView` and a `MGLMapView`. I need to use both of their delegate methods including `mapView:didAddAnnotationViews:` which is named the same for both maps. `Xcode` doesn't like this:

[image]

Is it possible to use both of these delegate methods in the same `viewController`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work, but you could try declaring the method just once, like this:

```
- (void)mapView:(id)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(id)views {}
```

And inside the method you check the class of the mapView and do what you must do in each case

Comment: I thought that it had worked, but on closer inspection when the method is called by each map it does not send the `views`.

Comment: Well, you'll need to create two different delegates, for each map then. In your viewController you instantiate them and implement your own protocol.